# When I Scroll the content of pages goes behind search bar and text widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test, flutter-android

My Widget Structure is as following

When the Main PageView index is 0 then Explore() Widget is called, else Category() widget is called

```
Align(
  alignment: Alignment.center,
  child: PageView.builder(
    controller: _controller,
    onPageChanged: (val) {
      setState(() {
        currentIndex = val;
      });
    },
    itemCount: 2,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return index == 0 ? Explore() : CategoryWrapper();
    },
  ),
),
```

Inside Explore() Widget I have a screenshot of the widget tree

[Widget tree of the explore widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPEWm.png)

My issue is whenever I scroll in explore page the content hide inside the search bar, can anyone please help me to figure the problem.

[Screenshot of the page when it loads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8sOB.png)

[Screenshot of the page when you scroll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26Rn2.jpg)

Comment: What debugging have you tried?

Comment: please, post your code in order to get a good response.